# AWS and o365 emails are delayed

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have a problem with sending transactional emails out of our web app. When number of sent emails was increasing some of the emails were delivered with delay - even up to 300min.

Using Amazon AWS and o365 smpt server.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon AWS has email sending limitations on your account using default port (if you are using external email solution)?

It's resulting like some emails are delivered with delay (up to 300 min in our case).

To save your time please take a look this thread https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=37650

**Solution:** https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request

Hope that this saves your time too.